# Zoo keeper SASL security

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kerberos, jaas, sasl

I'm using zookeeper 3.4.12 version and when trying to enable SASL 
found below error. Can someone help on this.

```
Client {
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
 useKeyTab=true
 storeKey=true
 useTicketCache=true
 keyTab="/tmp/kafka/zookeeper.service.keytab
 principal="zookeeper/chefclient.xyz.local@XYZ.LOCAL";
};
```

Error :

> 2018-11-02 09:35:01,998] ERROR SASL authentication failed using login context 'Client' with exception: {} (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
>   javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Error in authenticating with a Zookeeper Quorum member: the quorum member's saslToken is null

Comment: [2018-11-02 10:05:24,321] ERROR SASL authentication failed using login context 'Client' with exception: {} (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Error in authenticating with a Zookeeper Quorum member: the quorum member's saslToken is null.
        at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.createSaslToken(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:279)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.respondToServer(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:242)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.readResponse

Comment: What changes have you made? Have you check this section in the Kafka docs: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#zk_authz

Answer (score 1):

Issue is fixed, spaces in jaas were causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, you are missing a double quotation mark at

```
keyTab="/tmp/kafka/zookeeper.service.keytab
```

Comment: Look like I've missed it while posting the question, it's there. But still having the same problem do you what it could be

Answer (score 0):

First step in Zookeeper security is to secure quorum peers communication. Complete explanation [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/Server-Server+mutual+authentication).

Your Zookeeper jaas file should have **QuorumServer** and **QuorumLearner** sections.

Next, you can secure communication between Zookeeper cluster and clients as Kafka. Full explanation [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/Client-Server+mutual+authentication)

You add a **Server** section in Zookeeper jaas file and your Kafka jaas file should have a **Client** section

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem...

```
SaslException: Error in authenticating with a Zookeeper Quorum member: the quorum member's saslToken is null
```

This error was also in the Zookeeper Server log:

```
ERROR [NIOWorkerThread-6:ZooKeeperServer@1191] - cnxn.saslServer is null: cnxn object did not initialize its saslServer properly.
```

My configuration, using mutual kerberos authentication between zookeeper instances.

## The solution

**Missing "Server" Section**

My problem was that I didn't have the `Server` section present in my server jaas configuration for Zookeeper.

I need something like:

```
QuorumServer {
       com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
       useKeyTab=true
       keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/zookeeper.keytab"
       storeKey=true
       useTicketCache=false
       debug=false
       principal="zookeeper/zk1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM";
};

QuorumLearner {
       com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
       useKeyTab=true
       keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/zookeeper.keytab"
       storeKey=true
       useTicketCache=false
       debug=false
       principal="zookeeper/zk2.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM";
};

Server {
       com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
       useKeyTab=true
       keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/zookeeper.keytab"
       storeKey=true
       useTicketCache=false
       principal="zookeeper/zk3.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM";
};
```

When clients connect to Zookeeper they will authenticate against the `Server` section of this configuration. This is required for SASL to work.

Also make sure you have `conf/java.env` set with something like:

```sh
SERVER_JVMFLAGS="${SERVER_JVMFLAGS} -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/zookeeper/conf/server-jaas.conf"
CLIENT_JVMFLAGS="${CLIENT_JVMFLAGS} -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/zookeeper/conf/client-jaas.conf"
```